# Is Firebase Storage Connection possible for TypeScript/HTML/CSS Project WITHOUT Angular or React

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

My goal for the project portion is to be able to have a functioning login and register page using TypeScript.

Currently my code works without a database, but I wanted to use Firebase to register user's usernames and passwords, so they can login with ease.

The only tutorial I have found only use Firebase with Angular or React, and I was wondering if there was a way to use Firebase storage without it?

The IDE I am using is Intellij.

For now Firebase would be saving the username and password, but later my plan is to use Firebase Storage to save some text data to the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase can be used without any specific framework. While there may be binding libraries to make it easier to integrate with common frameworks (such as Angular and React), the base Firebase JavaScript SDK for the web is completely framework-agnostic.

The Firebase documentation doesn't assume any specific web framework, so I recommend starting there: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start.

I also recommend taking the Firebase codelab for web developers, which also doesn't require any specific web framework: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/